# PHP creating a multidimensional array of message threads from a multidimensional array (IMAP)

Tags: php, email, imap

My question is the following:

If you look below you'll see there is a datastructure with message ids and then the final datastructure containing the message details which should be aggregated from `imap_fetch_overview`. The message ids are from `imap_thread`. The problem is its not putting the email details in the position where the message id is.

Here is my datastructure:

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 9
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 11
    )
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => messageDetails for id 5
        [1] => messageDetails for id 9
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => messageDetails for id 10
        [1] => messageDetails for id 11
    )
```

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
$emails = imap_fetch_overview($imap, implode(',',$ids));

// root is the array index position of the threads message, such as 5 or 10
foreach($threads as $root => $messages){

    // id is the id being given to us from `imap_thread`
    foreach($message as $key => $id){

      foreach($emails as $index => $email){

         if($id === $email->msgno){
             $threads[$root][$key] = $email;
             break;
          }
      }
    }
 }
```

Here is a printout from one of the $emails:

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [subject] => Cloud Storage Dump
        [from] => Josh Doe
        [to] => jondoe@domain.com
        [date] => Mon, 21 Jan 2013 23:18:00 -0500
        [message_id] => <50FE12F8.9050506@domain.com>
        [size] => 2559
        [uid] => 5
        [msgno] => 5
        [recent] => 0
        [flagged] => 0
        [answered] => 1
        [deleted] => 0
        [seen] => 0
        [draft] => 0
        [udate] => 1358828308
    )
```

If you notice, the msgno is 5 which corrolates to the `$id`, so technically the data should be populating into the final datastructure.

Also, this seems like an inefficient way to handle this.

Please let me know if I you need any additional clarification.

**UPDATE CODE**

This code is a combination of code I found on php api and some fixes by me. What I think is problematic still is the `$root`.

```
$addedEmails = array();
$thread = imap_thread($imap);
foreach ($thread as $i => $messageId) { 
    list($sequence, $type) = explode('.', $i); 
    //if type is not num or messageId is 0 or (start of a new thread and no next) or is already set 
   if($type != 'num' || $messageId == 0 || ($root == 0 && $thread[$sequence.'.next'] == 0) || isset($rootValues[$messageId])) { 
    //ignore it 
    continue; 
} 

if(in_array($messageId, $addedEmails)){
    continue;
}
array_push($addedEmails,$messageId);

//if this is the start of a new thread 
if($root == 0) { 
    //set root 
    $root = $messageId; 
} 

//at this point this will be part of a thread 
//let's remember the root for this email 
$rootValues[$messageId] = $root; 

//if there is no next 
if($thread[$sequence.'.next'] == 0) { 
    //reset root 
    $root = 0; 
    } 
  }
$ids=array();
$threads = array();
foreach($rootValues as $id => $root){
    if(!array_key_exists($root,$threads)){
        $threads[$root] = array();
    }
    if(!in_array($id,$threads[$root])){
        $threads[$root][] = $id;
       $ids[]=$id;
    }
 }
 $emails = imap_fetch_overview($imap, implode(',', array_keys($rootValues)));

 $keys = array();
 foreach($emails as $k => $email)
 {
$keys[$email->msgno] = $k;
 }

 $threads = array_map(function($thread) use($emails, $keys)
{
// Iterate emails in these threads
return array_map(function($msgno) use($emails, $keys)
{
    // Swap the msgno with the email details
    return $emails[$keys[$msgno]];

}, $thread);
}, $threads);
```

Comment: What is `$root`?  What are you trying to accomplish with the nested `foreach` loops?  It seems like you should be iterating over `$emails`, but some more clarification of what you're trying to do is necessary.

Comment: You might want to look at one of the comments in the php manual for `imap_thread`.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-thread.php#104056  I think this is exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Threads can branch... how are you supposed to handle not only `(1 2 3)` but also `(1 2 (3 4 (5 6) 7) 8 9)`?

Comment: @Wrikken I don't know anything about that situation. Can you assist?

Comment: @jkushner: I did my best to tell a bit / code a bit around that problem. However, branching means the resulting array does tend to look a lot different then what you're working with now, so I don't know whether it's what you're looking for. YMMV, but there it is.

Comment: @Wrikken I need a little bit of time to digest this. It looks like the solution I would need though now that I understand your concern about branching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that in php whatever function you use it will be finally converted to some sort of loop.
There are, however some steps you could take to make it more efficient and they are different in PHP 5.5 and in 5.3/5.4.

### PHP 5.3/5.4 way

The most efficient way of doing this would be to split the function to 2 separate steps.
In first step you would generate a map of keys for the list of emails.

```
$keys = array();
foreach($emails as $k => $email)
{
    $keys[$email->msgno] = $k;
}
```

In 2nd step you iterate all values in the multi-dimensional $threads and replace them with the email details:

```
// Iterate threads
$threads = array_map(function($thread) use($emails, $keys)
{
    // Iterate emails in these threads
    return array_map(function($msgno) use($emails, $keys)
    {
        // Swap the msgno with the email details
        return $emails[$keys[$msgno]];

    }, $thread);

}, $threads);
```

Proof of concept: http://pastebin.com/rp5QFN4J

Explanation of keyword **use** in anonymous functions:

In order to make use of variables defined in the parent scope, it is possible to import variables from the parent scope into the closure scope with the **use ()** keyword. Although it was introduced in PHP 5.3 it hasn't been documented in the official PHP manual yet. There's only a draft document on php's wiki here https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures#userland_perspective

### PHP 5.5

One of the new features in this version enables you to use generators, which have significantly smaller memory thumbprint thus are more efficient.

Explanation of keyword **yield** in generators:

The heart of a generator function is the **yield** keyword. In its simplest form, a yield statement looks much like a return statement, except that instead of stopping execution of the function and returning, yield instead provides a value to the code looping over the generator and pauses execution of the generator function.

1st step:

```
function genetateKeyMap($emails)
{
    foreach($emails as $k => $email)
    {
        // Yielding key => value pair to result set
        yield $email->msgno => $k;
    }
};
$keys = iterator_to_array(genetateKeyMap($emails));
```

2nd step:

```
function updateThreads($emails, $threads, $keys)
{
    foreach($threads as $thread)
    {
        $array = array();

        // Create a set of detailed emails
        foreach($thread as $msgno)
        {
            $array[] = $emails[$keys[$msgno]];
        }

        // Yielding array to result set
        yield $array;
    }
};
$threads = iterator_to_array(updateThreads($emails, $threads, $keys));
```

A few words about the values being returned by genrators:

Generators return an object which is an instance of SPL Iterator thus it needs to use iterator_to_array() in order to convert it into exactly the same array structure your code is expecting. You don't need to do this, but it would require an update of your code following the generator function, which could be even more efficient.

Proof of concept: http://pastebin.com/9Z4pftBH

### Testing Performance:

I generated a list of 7000 threads with 5 messages each and tested the performance of each method (avg from 5 tests):

```
                   Takes:       Memory used:
                   ----------------------------
3x foreach():      2.8s              5.2 MB
PHP 5.3/5.4 way    0.061s            2.7 MB
PHP 5.5 way        0.036s            2.7 MB
```

Although the results on your machine/server might be different but the overview shows that the 2-step method is around 45-77 times faster than using 3 foreach loops

Test script: http://pastebin.com/M40hf0x7

Comment: This is an excellent answer. My only question is, I see that I'm not obtaining all of my emails from calling `imap_thread`. Do you know if there's a clause to using that?

Comment: I think you should ask your email provider. All emails should be returned by default

Comment: Can you look over my code I appended and tell me if theres anything not kosher? Maybe I'm discluding messages?

Comment: That I am not sure. It would be better if you took one of the emails you expect to be there (but it's not) and see whether it's being returned in imap_thread(). If it is, it would mean you have an error

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. I am going to wait a few days, however as of now I find your answer to be the best thus far. Thanks!

Comment: One last question. Can you explain the code containing array_map and use(). Ive never heard of use() before, and I'd like to know what exactly is going on. Also, a brief explanation of the word yield in your php5.5 code would be beneficial. And, in PHP 5.5, are all classes now iterators? Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with short explanation of yield and use() keywords, you should be able to find more details on the net easily though.

Comment: That's so weird. I was just signing on to write you that I thought more about it and your answer was best. I was blown away by the other answer and I knew it was a mistake to mark that one as best. I'm going to try and see if i can change it. If not, I'm sorry. I hope this doesn't deter you from answering more of my questions.

Comment: I changed it to your answer. Unfortunately, the bounty is already provided. I think, however, he deserved the bounty because he touched an answer none of you got to. On the other hand, your answer was best. So everything worked out in the end.

Comment: Ah well, `yield`-ing is a fine topic and answer, but it depends on overhead to get the resource to yield. Fwiw: when getting more `imap` message, and you _need_ them all, it is usually more effecient to get _all_ on 1 go instead of yielding. If however, you only need a subset, have limited memory, or the difference in overhead in getting one or all items in neglibale, `yield`-ing is _awesome_. I gather you want to bounty to go here, so I'll add it back to the question & award it here as soon as it lets me ;)

Comment: OK, bounty in 24 hours.

Comment: You know, the most awesome thing is that people come here to share their knowledge end experience and they aren't paid for that, moreover they don't expect to be awarded or glorified or at least most of them. I'm really glad I could add something to help you and perhaps somebody else digging for an answer for same or similar issue in the future. In fact these points are always something to make you happier but they won't replace money you make at work =]

Comment: In fact I've found so many answers on SO which saved me weeks if not months of work that I'd always be thankful to people like you Wrikken. And no worries jkuser, I see that you have a lot of question and I'll try helping you out with some of them when I have a few spare minutes

Answer (score 2):

When you print_r the $emails array what structure you get? Maybe the below should do it?

```
 $threads[$root][$key] = $emails[$key];
```

Comment: can you provide what `print_r($emails)` returns per this user's suggestion?

Comment: if you try print_r($emails) what you get?

Comment: change ($id === $email->msgno) to ($id == $email['msgno'])

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to PHP right now, to test, but I believe what you're trying to do is something like

```
foreach($emails as $email) {
    foreach($threads as $root => $messages) {
        foreach($messages as $index =>$message_id){
            if($message_id == $email->msgno){
                 $threads[$root][$index] = $email;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, even if this works, there is probably a more efficient way to approach this than with three nested loops.  What is your reason for needing to store the output in this format?

Comment: I recognize that there is a better approach, I just don't know what it is. I thought I put on my description that i was looking for the most optimized version possible.

Answer (score 0):

An implementation with branches (more complex then a single thread `array('5' => array(5,7,8))`, but unless I was only talking to 1 person, threads always tend to branch for me personally, so I'll have to cope with the added complexity)

```
<?php 
$threads = imap_thread($imap, SE_UID);
/*
 * threads returns entries as follows:
 * <id>.num = <messageid>
 * <id>.next = <messageid of first reply to <id>>,  0 = no replies
 * <id>.branch = <messageid of nth. reply to <parent of id>>, 0 = no more branches
 * Keep in mind: _every_ message 'starts' a branch, but that may be empty.
 */
$nodes = array( 0 => array( 'children' => array()));
$ids = array();
foreach ($threads as $key => $val) {
    list($treeid,$type) = explode('.',$key);
    switch($type){
        case 'num':
            //the actual message number of this tree node
            //store id for retrieval later:
            $ids[$val] = null;
            if($val==0){
                //return to root
                $nodes[$treeid] = &$nodes[0];
            } else {
                if(!isset($nodes[$treeid])) $nodes[$treeid] = array();
                $nodes[$treeid] = array_merge($nodes[$treeid],array(
                    'id' => $val,
                    'message' => &$ids[$val],
                    'treeid' => $treeid));
            }
            break;
        case 'next':
            // 0 means no next message, anything else is a reply
            if (0!=$val) {
                if(!isset($nodes[$val])) $nodes[$val] = array('parent' => $treeid);
                $nodes[$treeid][] = &$nodes[$val];
            }
            break;
        case 'branch':
            //0 means end of branch, a number means continue as sibling \
            //so we need to know the parent
            if (0!=$val) {
                if(!isset($nodes[$val])) $nodes[$val] = array('parent' => $nodes[$treeid]['parent']?:0);
                $nodes[$nodes[$val]['parent']][] = &$nodes[$val];
            }
            break;
        default:
            trigger_error("Unknown tree traverse-type: $type", E_USER_WARNING);
    }
}
//the great thing is we can get all our ID's at once:
$keystofetch = implode(',',array_filter(array_keys($nodes)));
$messages = imap_fetch_overview($imap,$keystofetch, FT_UID);
foreach($messages as $message){
    // you can of course store the _whole_ message in this thread like:
    // $nodes[$message->uid]['message'] = get_object_vars($message);
    // and do what you like with $tree[0]['children'] (be it a resursive array iterator,
    // or a  resursive function, your pick.
    // However, for this example we are going to only set message to a string of p.o.c 
    // (which is also nicer for our treeiterator)
    $ids[$message->uid] = $message->from.':'.$message->subject;
}
//let's show the result:
$it = new RecursiveTreeIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($nodes[0]),
    RecursiveTreeIterator::BYPASS_CURRENT,
    CachingIterator::TOSTRING_USE_KEY);
foreach($it as $key => $item){
    echo "$key".(is_scalar($item)?': '.$item:'').PHP_EOL;
}
```

Which give us:

```
|-children
|-0
| |-parent: 0
| |-id: 35
| |-message: Friend Purple Acc2 <purple2@example.com>:A bigger message thread
| |-treeid: 1
| \-0
|   |-parent: 1
|   |-id: 7
|   |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|   |-treeid: 2
|   \-0
|     |-parent: 2
|     |-id: 11
|     |-message: Friend Grey <grey@example.com>Re: A bigger message thread
|     |-treeid: 3
|     \-0
|       |-parent: 3
|       |-id: 39
|       |-message: Friend Purple Acc2 <purple2@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|       |-treeid: 4
|       \-0
|         |-parent: 4
|         |-id: 40
|         |-message: Friend Pink <pink@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|         |-treeid: 5
|         \-0
|           |-parent: 5
|           |-id: 38
|           |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|           |-treeid: 6
|           \-0
|             |-parent: 6
|             |-id: 12
|             |-message: Friend Pink <pink@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|             |-treeid: 7
|             \-0
|               |-parent: 7
|               |-id: 25
|               |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|               |-treeid: 8
|               \-0
|                 |-parent: 8
|                 |-id: 19
|                 |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                 |-treeid: 9
|                 \-0
|                   |-parent: 9
|                   |-id: 23
|                   |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                   |-treeid: 10
|                   \-0
|                     |-parent: 10
|                     |-id: 30
|                     |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                     |-treeid: 11
|                     \-0
|                       |-parent: 11
|                       |-id: 2
|                       |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |-treeid: 12
|                       |-0
|                       | |-parent: 12
|                       | |-id: 20
|                       | |-message: Me <me@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       | |-treeid: 13
|                       | \-0
|                       |   |-parent: 13
|                       |   |-id: 1
|                       |   |-message: Fiend Silver <silver@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |   |-treeid: 14
|                       |   \-0
|                       |     |-parent: 14
|                       |     |-id: 41
|                       |     |-message: Fiend Silver <silver@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |     |-treeid: 15
|                       |     \-0
|                       |       |-parent: 15
|                       |       |-id: 27
|                       |       |-message: Friend Grey <grey@example.com>Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |       |-treeid: 16
|                       |       \-0
|                       |         |-parent: 16
|                       |         |-id: 17
|                       |         |-message: Friend Magenta <magenta@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         |-treeid: 17
|                       |         |-0
|                       |         | |-parent: 17
|                       |         | |-id: 31
|                       |         | |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         | |-treeid: 18
|                       |         | \-0
|                       |         |   |-parent: 18
|                       |         |   |-id: 4
|                       |         |   |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         |   |-treeid: 19
|                       |         |   \-0
|                       |         |     |-parent: 19
|                       |         |     |-id: 37
|                       |         |     |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         |     |-treeid: 20
|                       |         |     \-0
|                       |         |       |-parent: 20
|                       |         |       |-id: 24
|                       |         |       |-message: Friend Purple Acc2 <purple2@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         |       |-treeid: 21
|                       |         |       \-0
|                       |         |         |-parent: 21
|                       |         |         |-id: 13
|                       |         |         |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |         |         \-treeid: 22
|                       |         \-1
|                       |           |-parent: 17
|                       |           |-id: 15
|                       |           |-message: Friend Grey <grey@example.com>Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |           |-treeid: 23
|                       |           \-0
|                       |             |-parent: 23
|                       |             |-id: 18
|                       |             |-message: Friend Magenta <magenta@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |             |-treeid: 24
|                       |             \-0
|                       |               |-parent: 24
|                       |               |-id: 45
|                       |               |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                       |               \-treeid: 25
|                       \-1
|                         |-parent: 12
|                         |-id: 46
|                         |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                         |-treeid: 26
|                         \-0
|                           |-parent: 26
|                           |-id: 29
|                           |-message: Fiend Silver <silver@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                           |-treeid: 27
|                           \-0
|                             |-parent: 27
|                             |-id: 26
|                             |-message: Friend Magenta <magenta@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                             |-treeid: 28
|                             |-0
|                             | |-parent: 28
|                             | |-id: 34
|                             | |-message: Friend Grey <grey@example.com>Re: A bigger message thread
|                             | \-treeid: 29
|                             |-1
|                             | |-parent: 28
|                             | |-id: 33
|                             | |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                             | |-treeid: 30
|                             | \-0
|                             |   |-parent: 30
|                             |   |-id: 36
|                             |   |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                             |   |-treeid: 31
|                             |   |-0
|                             |   | |-parent: 31
|                             |   | |-id: 10
|                             |   | |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                             |   | \-treeid: 32
|                             |   \-1
|                             |     |-parent: 31
|                             |     |-id: 48
|                             |     |-message: Friend Pink <pink@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                             |     \-treeid: 33
|                             \-2
|                               |-parent: 28
|                               |-id: 47
|                               |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                               |-treeid: 34
|                               \-0
|                                 |-parent: 34
|                                 |-id: 5
|                                 |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                 |-treeid: 35
|                                 \-0
|                                   |-parent: 35
|                                   |-id: 3
|                                   |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                   |-treeid: 36
|                                   \-0
|                                     |-parent: 36
|                                     |-id: 21
|                                     |-message: Friend Yellow <yellow@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                     |-treeid: 37
|                                     \-0
|                                       |-parent: 37
|                                       |-id: 8
|                                       |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                       |-treeid: 38
|                                       \-0
|                                         |-parent: 38
|                                         |-id: 43
|                                         |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                         |-treeid: 39
|                                         \-0
|                                           |-parent: 39
|                                           |-id: 28
|                                           |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                           |-treeid: 40
|                                           \-0
|                                             |-parent: 40
|                                             |-id: 42
|                                             |-message: Friend Brown <brown@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                             |-treeid: 41
|                                             \-0
|                                               |-parent: 41
|                                               |-id: 22
|                                               |-message: Friend Purple <purple@example.com>:Re: A bigger message thread
|                                               \-treeid: 42
|-1
| |-parent: 0
| |-id: 9
| |-message: Friend Blue <blue@example.com>:RE: A bigger message thread
| \-treeid: 43
|-2
| \-parent: 0
|-3
| |-parent: 44
| |-id: 49
| |-message: Some Subcription <foo@example.com>:Newsletter #1
| \-treeid: 45
|-4
| |-parent: 44
| |-id: 50
| |-message: Some Subcription <foo@example.com>:Newsletter #2
| \-treeid: 46
\-5
  |-parent: 0
  |-id: 32
  |-message: Friend Red <red@example.com>:A second mainthread
  |-treeid: 47
  \-0
    |-parent: 47
    |-id: 16
    |-message: Friend Black <black@example.com>:Re: A second mainthread
    |-treeid: 48
    \-0
      |-parent: 48
      |-id: 14
      |-message: Friend Red <red@example.com>:Re: A second mainthread
      |-treeid: 49
      \-0
        |-parent: 49
        |-id: 6
        |-message: Friend White <white@example.com>:Re: A second mainthread
        |-treeid: 50
        \-0
          |-parent: 50
          |-id: 44
          |-message: Fiend Silver <silver@example.com>:Re: A second mainthread
          \-treeid: 51
```

A few things of note:

- The first incarnation of this script incorrectly added branches to
  the first child of a node instead of the actual node itself, which is
  fixed now by also storing its parent.
- `imap_thread` isn't perfect: we see `id=9` as an orphan, although it seems it should be in the first thread somewhere. However, due to
  the headers not mentioning this, Google Apps here decided to make it
  it's own node.
- The 3rd (key=2) entry is a method to 'return to root', as the `N.num.N.branch,N.next` method has apparently no other way to return
  to root. This is the `/return to root $nodes[$treeid] = &$nodes[0];`
  bit. You can/should filter this out after determining all other
  nodes, but you need it to build the array at first.

To get only the nodes starting new threads (Nth reply on message, N>1):

```
$threads = imap_thread($imap, SE_UID);
$branchestarts = array();
foreach($threads as $key => $value){
    list($num,$type) = explode('.',$key);
    if (
        $type=='num'                     // an id
        && $value == 0                   // which is actually root
        && isset($threads[$num.'.next']) // then check for next
        && isset($threads[$threads[$num.'.next'].'.num'])
    ){
        $branchestarts[] = $threads[$threads[$num.'.next'].'.num'];
    } else if(
        $type=='branch'                   // branch movement
        && $value != 0                    // not back
        && isset($threads[$value.'.num']) // sanity: target exists
        && $threads[$value.'.num'] != 0   // and is not a return to root
    ){
        $branchestarts[] = $threads[$value.'.num'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($branchestarts);
```

Which gives us:

```
[35,15,46,33,48,47,9,49,50,32]
```

And indeed, 35,49,50 & 32 are starts of threads, 9 is recognized as such by the imap server too, and the rest are 2nd or more replies starting their own branches.

Now, you *could* indeed split out branches as seperate conversation, but as you can see, these are often only 1 or 2 replies more, longer threads tend to develop a bit more rarely. 
To see how these 'branches' go:

```
$branches = array();
$currenttree = null;
foreach($threads as $key => $value){
    list($num,$type) = explode('.',$key);
    switch($type){
        case 'num':
            //nothing
            break;
        case 'next':
            if(is_null($currenttree)) $currenttree = &$branches[$threads[$value.'.num']];
            if($value && isset($threads[$value.'.num'])) $currenttree[] = $threads[$value.'.num'];
            break;
        case 'branch':
            unset($currenttree);
            if($value && $threads[$value.'.num']){
                $branches[$threads[$value.'.num']] = array($threads[$value.'.num']);
                $currenttree =& $branches[$threads[$value.'.num']];
            }
    }
}
echo json_encode($branches, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Which gives you roots & branches & their replies:

```
{
    "35": [
        35,
        7,
        11,
        39,
        40,
        38,
        12,
        25,
        19,
        23,
        30,
        2,
        20,
        1,
        41,
        27,
        17,
        31,
        4,
        37,
        24,
        13
    ],
    "15": [
        15,
        18,
        45
    ],
    "46": [
        46,
        29,
        26,
        34
    ],
    "33": [
        33,
        36,
        10
    ],
    "48": [
        48
    ],
    "47": [
        47,
        5,
        3,
        21,
        8,
        43,
        28,
        42,
        22
    ],
    "9": [
        9
    ],
    "49": [
        49
    ],
    "50": [
        50
    ],
    "32": [
        32,
        16,
        14,
        6,
        44
    ]
}
```

With some slight alterations we can get the messages in there:

```
$branches = array();
$currenttree = null;
$messages = array();
foreach($threads as $key => $value){
    list($num,$type) = explode('.',$key);
    switch($type){
        case 'num':
            //nothing
            break;
        case 'next':
            if(is_null($currenttree)) $currenttree = &$branches[$threads[$value.'.num']];
            if($value && isset($threads[$value.'.num'])) $currenttree[] = &$messages[$threads[$value.'.num']];
            break;
        case 'branch':
            unset($currenttree);
            if($value && $threads[$value.'.num']){
                $branches[$threads[$value.'.num']] = array(&$messages[$threads[$value.'.num']]);
                $currenttree =& $branches[$threads[$value.'.num']];
            } else {
                $currenttree = null;
            }
    }
}
$keystofetch = implode(',',array_filter(array_keys($messages)));
foreach(imap_fetch_overview($imap,$keystofetch,FT_UID) as $message){
        $messages[$message->uid] = $message;
}
echo json_encode($branches);//won't show it's output, this answer is to large as it is ;)
```

Another option is to just sort them by datetime value, which would be alright for conversations with little/negligible branching, probably making most of the code you are planning just work.

A combination of the two would be 'moving branches', follow threads in series, so this:

```
 1       2013-06-01
   2     2013-06-02
     3   2013-06-03
   4     2013-06-03
     5   2013-06-04
```

Becomes a sequence of `1,2,3,4,5` but a reply on `3` would resort it:

```
 1       2013-06-01
   4     2013-06-03
     5   2013-06-04
   2     2013-06-02
     3   2013-06-03
       6 2013-06-05
```

Making it a sequence of `1,4,5,2,3,6`, which would keep it a logically flowing conversation, with always the thread/branch with the last reply as last.

Comment: With this solution, I'd need to not only grab the root nodes but also scan the children and find new branching threads. Id like to end up with an array that would have the root nodes with their respective children, and then i can visualize having the emails that were branched being on the same level as the root nodes with their own children. Does that make sense? I can try to explain it better.

Comment: Hm, I'm not very clear on what you mean. Do you mean 'find any node (including rootnode) which has more then 1 direct reply, and return it's 1st to Nth child if rootnode, and 2nd to Nth child if non-rootnode'?

Comment: If you look at my datastructure i provided, youll see that i have a one-dimensional array of messages, separated by the root nodes and then encapsulating the messages corrolating to that specific root node. Id like to have that, as is, and then have branched children be pushed to that datastructure as if it was a root node. So, in the end, I have a one-dimensional array of message threads, whether it be from the imap_thread or a branched child. Better explanation? I can do more if you still dont understand.

Comment: SO, that would be in the first example, nodes with id 35 & 32 (start of conversation), and 15,46,47 & 9 as 'new branches'?

Comment: Precisely. I want the branches for 15,46,47,and 9 to be merged into the data structure i have. My reasoning is, i want to display the threads in my html message list, and i imagine that branches should be treated as a new thread. So, assuming 15,46,47, and 9 are starts of new threads, doesn't that make sense to have them in my final threads datastructure so when i loop through it in my html list they will be there as if it was a new message. Do you see any flaws in this?

Comment: Well, I prefer to see my e-mails threaded, but I get that in this day and age of to many hotmail & gmail use instead of actual clients this can in HTML contexts become undesirable. I'll edit something in, finding rootnodes is relatively simple.

Comment: Also, I am storing in the database a parent_id to the messages. Root nodes would have a parent id of 0, and children nodes will all have an id of the root node for its parent. I'd then order by time to organize it by the newest time. With branching, the complexity becomes extremely difficult for me because I need to traverse the tree, find the branches, insert the branch root into the database with a parent of 0, and traverse its children and insert an id of the branched root. If we can figure out a way to include the database logic in, I can think for a moment if there's anything remaining.

Comment: Im sorry.I didn't mean to bombard you with non-similar tasks, such as database logic. I'm not nearly as proficient as you are, and it would take me a very long time to figure out a few points which could take you not very much time at all. I appreciate your assistance in all of this.

Comment: Hm editing something in, but I've spotted an error in the algorithm... to little branching, hold on ;)

Comment: Well, suffice to say I now know why my e-mail client has a whopping 6 threading-options.. There's a little bit of error still in there, but it's 02:00 at night a.t.m, if you'll bear with me I'll revisit this tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looking forward to seeing your work tomorrow.

Comment: Just checking in to see if you had any chance in working more on this post. Talk to you soon!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, life got a little bit in the way, update in +/- 9 hours when I'm home again.

Comment: No problem. The bounty ends in 22 hrs and I am not sure what happens after the bounty expires.

Comment: Heh, I have more points then I know what to do with, don't care about bounties :P. The edit is there now though.

Comment: this looks very nice, but how do I retrieve the children for each of the root nodes?

Comment: Hm, can you elaborate on that, what is the exact structure you'd like to end up with?

Comment: Well, I have the root nodes, and I need the children of each root

Comment: Editing something in, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The goal was to have an array with root nodes and then each root node was to have its children, hence creating a tree-like structure of roots and children. If you look at my question, i provide a datastructure id like (the one with 5 and 10 as the root nodes)

Comment: Ah well, final juice to add the messages in there... hope it is to your liking, because after that I'm gone for the day again :P

Comment: I'm much appreciative to your help. I have a much better understanding of emails now. Your assistance has helped me grow as an engineer as well. Thanks a lot.